# Efficient algorithm for finding the number within an interval given its prime factors

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, prime-factorization

Suppose we are given two integers $\ell$ and $h$ such that $\ell \leq h$ and a list of distinct prime numbers $P = [p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n]$ (sorted in ascending order). We are interested in finding an integer $a$ (if any) such that:

1. the prime factors of $a$ are every element in $P$ (mathematically $a = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2} \dots p_n^{e_n}$ for some $e_i \geq 1$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$),
2. $a$ is between $\ell$ and $h$ (i.e., $\ell \leq a \leq h$).

Here, we just want a value of $a$, but it would be nice if $a$ is the smallest number satisfying the condition. My attempts so far are as follows. Define $f = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i$, checks if $\ell \leq f \leq h$. If $h < f$, the integer $a$ does not exist. If $f < \ell $, I consider two options below:

1. We multiply $f$ by $p_1$ (the smallest prime in the list) repeatedly until we get an expression $f \cdot p_1^{e_1} \geq \ell $. However, this approach does not always work (see the example below).
2. We compute $e = \lfloor \log_{f}\ell \rfloor$ and define $p_1 \cdot f^e$. We sometimes have $p_1 \cdot f^e \geq \ell$ or $ \ell \leq f^{(e+1)} \leq h $, but unfortunately, this approach does not always work (see the example below).

The counterexample for both methods above is as follows. Let $\ell = 1000$, $h = 1100$, and $P = [3,7]$. We have $f = 3 \cdot 7 = 21$. If we use the first approach, we have the sequence $21, 63, 189, 567, 1701$; we do not find $a$ satisfying the condition. Using the second approach, we have $e = \lfloor \log_{21}1000 \rfloor = 2$. We do not find the solution because we have $3 \cdot f^e = 3 \cdot 21^2 = 1323 > 1100 $ and also $f^{(e+1)} = 21^3 = 9261$. However, a solution to this problem exists, i.e., $a = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 = 1029$.

Another approach is as follows, but I think it is not efficient and more cumbersome:

1. Define $g = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{d_i}$, initially all $d_i$ are set to $1$. We also define $f = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i$ as above. Notice that initially $g = f$.
2. Compute $b = \lceil \log_f h\rceil $. Observe that $f^b > h$.
3. Increment each $d_i$ one-by-one, i.e., the tuple $(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n)$ is incremented in lexicographic order. Each value $d_i$ is between $1$ and $b$ (inclusive).
4. The iteration terminates if we find $g$ such that $\ell \leq g \leq h$ or we obtain the condition $g > h$ (we have no solution).

However, in the last algorithm, there are at most $b$ iterations for each $d_i$; thus, it is inefficient.

Any idea to solve this efficiently? Or perhaps such a problem is at least as hard as the [integer factorization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity)?

Addendum: The problem does not seem easy and is probably NP-hard. Is there any way to prove the NP-hardness of such a problem? Is it possible to determine the exact computational complexity class of this problem?

Comment: I think it's more like the bin-packing problem, which is harder than integer factorization. In your example, you want positive integers $r,s$ such that $\log(1000/21)\le(\log3)r+(\log7)s\le\log(1100/21)$. You're filling a bin of size between $\log(1000/21)$ and $\log(1100/21)$ with objects of size $\log3$ and $\log7$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Does this imply that the above problem is NP-complete? Hence no efficient solution is known.

Comment: If your numbers are very large then you might perhaps need unlimited precision in your calculations, so it _might_ be harder than NP-complete. And because we have these irrational logarithms we might not be able to map every NP problem to this problem, so it might be less than NP complete. Either way, it will take about as much time as an NP-complete problem. Note that the time grows with the size of the data (number of bits) not the values. L, h up to 10^30 might not be a big deal.

Comment: @gnasher729 Any idea to prove the NP-hardness of such a problem? I conjecture that the problem is NP-hard even if the list $P$ contains exactly two elements. If $P$ contains two elements, we have something a bit harder than the famous integer factorization problem.

Comment: I too think that the general problem is NP-hard (I have no proof of this). But, I think it is good to mention that if $h/l$ is large enough, then the problem becomes easier to solve, since then approximation algorithms like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximation_algorithms) can be used (I think).

Comment: At the same time, if $h/l$ is very close to 1, then we can sieve the interval $[l,h]$ using the primes that are given. This is efficient if $h-l$ is not too big. Therefore, when we combine this with my previous comment, I think that the hardest case is when $h,l$ are large and $h/l$ is somewhat close to 1.

Comment: I have no idea for rigorous proofs , but I agree that this problem will be very hard in general , but I do not think that it is harder than NP-hard.

Comment: It has been four months, I am still waiting for rigorous proof.